# Setting selectedindex not triggering onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I am trying to change selectedindex of a select tag. But onchange event is not triggered while changing the index via jquery.

I am creating option for the select tag dynamically. I won't be knowing the values of option tag.

Is there any other method to achieve it?
Here is my code snippet. Feel free to give inputs.

```js
function callFunc(obj) {
  console.log(obj.value);
}

setTimeout(() => {
  $("#select1")[0].selectedIndex = 2;
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1" onchange="callFunc(this);">
  <option value='0'>select ....</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how do you create your select `dinamically`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to trigger the change yourself calling `change()` on the element. I have replaces the `selectedIndex` with `val` function's call. Also attach event handler using javascript, not via markup.

```js
const select = $("#select1");

select.on('change', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});

setTimeout(() => {
  select.val(2).change();
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option value='0'>select ....</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If the values is dynamic, how will I select it then ?

Comment: Didn't understand you. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: If I am creating options dynamically. How will I get the value to change the index. I saw `select.val(2).change();` is using value of option tag.

Comment: If you are creating your options dynamically and want to bind to some option by default, you need to know to which you want to bind. If you want to get the current value of the selected one, you can use `this.value` or `$(this).val()` to get the appropriate one.

Comment: this seems you have another question which is not included in the question above. anyway this is the answer of your question

Comment: You can still use your approach with `selectedIndex`, only after it you need to call `change()` on the `select`. `select[0].selectedIndex = 2;
  select.change();`

Comment: @Shubham You must be knowing what index to change before changing it.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan got you. Thanks .

Answer (score 9):

.. or using VanillaJS (favoring `event constructors` over `createEvent`):

```
function setSelectedIndex(el, index){
   el.selectedIndex = index;
   el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
}

setSelectedIndex(select1, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use trigger function of jQuery.

```js
function callFunc(obj) {
  console.log(obj.value);
}


setTimeout(function(e){ $("#select1").val(2).trigger('change'); }, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1" onchange="callFunc(this);">
  <option value='0'>select ....</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```